# I can't creating RTMP session on VideoCore

Tags: iphone, xcode, rtmp, flash-media-server, videocore

I am getting the following log while connecting on Adobe FMS server.

Do you have any solution?
Please help me.

```
ClientState: 1
ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
Want read:4096, read:2776
ClientState: 4
ClientState: 5
Not enough s2 size
Want read:1320, read:297
ClientState: 6
Tracking command(1, connect)
Want read:4096, read:230
Steam in buffer size:230
First byte:0x2, header type:0
Handle message:5
Received server window size: 2500000
Steam in buffer size:214
First byte:0x2, header type:0
Handle message:6
Received peer bandwidth limit: 49152 type: 2
Steam in buffer size:197
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke _error
Steam in buffer size:60
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke close
Steam in buffer size:30
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke close
~RTMPSession
```

Podfile looks like the following:

```
pod 'VideoCore/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/maxcampolo/VideoCore.git', :branch => 'update_headers'
pod 'glm', :git => 'https://github.com/maxcampolo/glm.git'
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this??